# CodeIgniter Emails always return false

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to send an email. My configuration in the `application/config/email.php` are as follows:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit("No direct script access allowed");

$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'my_host',    // My host name
    'smtp_port' => 2525,
    'smtp_user' => 'username',   // My username
    'smtp_pass' => 'password',   // My password
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE,
    'smtp_timeout' => 30,
    'newline' => "\r\n",
    'crlf' => "\r\n",
    'mailtype' => "text"
);
```

Assuming I'm using a controller called `Maintenance.php`, the setup in it are as follows:

```
<?php // Maintenance.php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit("No direct script access allowed");

class Maintenance extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Accra');    // This was to cater for an error given to me earlier

        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->from('the email I used in the email.php', "Name");
        $this->email->to('email to send to');
        $this->email->subject('Test email');
        $this->email->message("Testing the email class");

        var_dump($this->email->send());
        $this->email->print_debugger();
     }
}
```

After `var_dump()` I get `bool(false)`. Even though my environment is set to development, I still do not get any error message. The `$this->email->print_debugger()` is also not showing anything. I'm using *CodeIgniter 3.1.3*

Thanks for your help

Comment: you need to `echo  $this->email->print_debugger();`

Comment: Are you trying this on some web server or on local host?

Comment: `if (!$this->email->send()) {var_dump($this->email->print_debugger());}`

Comment: you can use swiftmailer inside codeigniter.if you want to use then tell me i will give you the code how to use swift mailer in codeigniter.

Comment: @simplysaif I'm using a web server

Comment: 'smtp_timeout' is the culprit set it higher than the default value which is 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all save your `email's configuration` like below in `application/config/email.php`

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit("No direct script access allowed");
$config['mail'] = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'my_host',    // My host name
    'smtp_port' => 2525,
    'smtp_user' => 'username',   // My username
    'smtp_pass' => 'password',   // My password
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE,
    'smtp_timeout' => 30,
    'newline' => "\r\n",
    'crlf' => "\r\n",
    'mailtype' => "text"
);
```

Then in controller `load email configuration` file and pass it to `email library` using `$this->email->initialize($configuration)` like below.

```
public function index()
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Accra');    // This was to cater for an error given to me earlier
        $this->config->load('email', TRUE);//load email config file
        $confiuration = $this->config->item('mail', 'email');//email configuration

        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->initialize($configuration);//initializes email configuration

        $this->email->from('the email I used in the email.php', "Name");
        $this->email->to('email to send to');
        $this->email->subject('Test email');
        $this->email->message("Testing the email class");

        var_dump($this->email->send());
        $this->email->print_debugger();
     }
```

Comment: I tried but I ended up with a new error, `Error 501: Sender address must contain a domain`. how do I fix that one too

Comment: see here https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/unable-to-send-mails-from-windows-mail-error-501/45c77ac9-36e1-4d2a-ba23-b3d4198c3a9a

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `'smtp_timeout' =>` configuration is set to a value higher than the default value which is `5`.

20 to about 30 should work.